# Howto extract blackframes and volumes info from video at the same time with ffmpeg/ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm extracting astats info with:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "amovie=video.flv,astats=metadata=1:reset=1" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags -print_format json
```

Blackframes info with:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "movie=video.flv,blackframe=1" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags -print_format json
```

But when I'm trying to combine filters like this:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "amovie=video.flv,astats=metadata=1:reset=1;movie=video.flv,blackframe=1" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags -print_format json
```

I've the following error: **Invalid filterchain containing an unlabelled output pad: "astats=metadata=1:reset=1;movie=video.flv,blackframe=1"**

How to combine output of two filters in a single json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When extracting multiple streams from lavfi graph, assign output pad labels of the form `out%d` starting with `out0`.

Use

`ffprobe -f lavfi -i "amovie=video.flv,astats=metadata=1:reset=1[out0];movie=video.flv,blackframe=1[out1]" -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time:frame_tags -print_format json`